# Linux remove ; from filenames

Tags: linux, filenames, mv

i have files in linux:

```
omer.dat;1
yossi.dat;4
```

I want change them to: (remove ;NUMBER)

```
omer.dat
yossi.dat
```

I try doing:

```
mv "$file" "${file%;*}"
```

But its not working

I tried doing something like:

```
mv omer.dat;1 omer.dat
```

Linux not find the file and not support ;

I want to rename all the files

Comment: Why is `mv "$file" "${file%;*}"` not working? It strips the (shortest) suffix matching the pattern, so it should work exactly as expected

Answer (score 1):

This `mv "$file" "${file%;*}"` should work. Maybe you need to populate the variable first? (I cannot tell from the question if that is happening or not):

```
for file in *\;*; do
  mv "$file" "${file%;*}";
done
```

If you have [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) installed on your system, it comes with a `rename` utility which allows you to apply a regular expression to file names:

```
rename 's/;[^;]*$//' *\;*
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `;` in a Linux command it treats it as the end of a command so when you write

```
mv omer.dat;1 omer.dat
```

It treats it as 2 separate commands like: `mv omer.dat` and `1 omer.dat`. Hence the error.
So to use `;` as a part of a name, use the following:

```
mv omer.dat\;1 omer.dat
```

The `\;` part will do the trick.

Now to generalise the situation, we can use `${file%;*}` this pattern, so if the original file name has `;` , this pattern removes all the characters from `;` (inclusive).
The full code will be like this:

```
files=`ls|grep "\;"`
for file in $files;do
    mv $file ${file%;*}
done
```

Comment: and how i can run this command for all the files ?

Comment: like mv "$file" "${file%;*}"

Comment: @OmerAsher I am editing my answer to give you full answer

Comment: ***Never*** use `for i in $(ls anything)`, see [**Bash Pitfalls #1**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). Instead `for file in *\;*; do ...` or pipe the output of `find` to `while read -r file; do ...`